# Android how to set Google Map Api Key dynamically not from AndroidManifest

Tags: android, metadata, android-manifest

I have a requirement to set google map Api key dynamically i.e form the code not from manifest .Currently I am getting this value form string.xml . Which is not the preferred way according to the requirement .

```
<meta-data`android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"`

   android:value="@string/map_api_key"
                         />
```

How can I set this value form code .

Answer (score 5):

The way you would do this is as a manifest placeholder.

In your AndroidManifest.xml put a variable declaration like this:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${mapsApiKey}"/>
```

then in your build.grade enter this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapsApiKey:"debugKey"]
    }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ mapsApiKey:"prodKey" ]
            }
        }
   }
```

Documentation is here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support

Note I'm making assumptions here about your use case.  This only applies if you're trying to swap out keys based on build type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
mMapView = new MapView(this, mapApiKey);
```

But you cannot both have the widget in your xml layout and set the API key in Java. In this case you will need to dynamically add the map to your layout.

Edit: from api v2, this is not possible, you have to set the api key in the manifest file.

Comment: mapApiKey is  a String .there  is no Constructor for  MapView(Context ,String) .

Comment: Seems like this is disabled since api v2. Google said in it's documentation: To access the Google Maps servers with the Maps API V2, you have to add a Maps API key to your application.... Add the key to your application by adding an element to your application's AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: So sad. A limitation I'd need to overcome somehow.