# Multiple Google Places API Key (in Library and Client Code) in the Same Android App

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-places-api, android-library, google-geocoder

We are building an Android SDK that internally uses Google Places API with a key specified in the manifest metadata as specified here https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

However, the clients using the our Android library might have their own google places api service registered in the client manifest file. This seems to generate a conflict. Is it possible to use 2 different Google places api in the same android app and somehow point to the different keys in the code ?

Comment: See if this helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243838/android-how-to-set-google-map-api-key-dynamically-not-from-androidmanifest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : API key Conflicts when merging a library into app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159075/android-api-key-conflicts-when-merging-a-library-into-app)